# Can you create sub-applications within applications in IIS/ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, .net-2.0

We have a global application (well out of my control) that runs a lot of sites.
I'd like to create a new application (as I cant extend etc) within a folder so it could be accessed as follows.

- http://www.domain.com/ < Global App
- http://www.domain.com/newapp < New App

Is this actually possible or just a pipe dream; I'm aware that its possible to set additional locations for assemblies (as per: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4191fzwb(VS.80).aspx) but a full app I'm not to sure.

Ta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a new virtual application from IIS under the main application, which is very easy but you do have to have access to IIS, obviously.

[See this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569797/creating-virtual-application-directory-in-physical-folder-on-iis-asp-net)

Comment: Ta; just trying to do away with IT excuses. I'll test it on my dev-server for extra embarrassing effect.

Comment: Should be easy enough! Good luck :-)